# How to bind a keydown to a button's click event UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a little UWP calculator app, and I'm trying to figure out how to bind a keyboard number to a button's click event x:Bind. In the case below I'm passing the Content "7" to a button RoutedEventArgs in the ViewModel. Ideally, I would just bind both the keyboard and numpad number 7 to the button in XAML without the need for a separate event handler. Or do I need to instead use a code behind event handler which binds the numbers to the ViewModel's event handler?

```
<Button x:Name="SevenButton"
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Content="7"
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnNumberBtnClick}"></Button>

//ViewModel
public void OnNumberBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    if ((_outputValue) == "0" || (isOperationPerformed))
        _outputValue = "";

    isOperationPerformed = false;
    Button numberBtnClick = (Button)sender;

    if ((string)numberBtnClick.Content == ".")
    {
        if (!_outputValue.Contains("."))
        {
            OutputValue = OutputValue + numberBtnClick.Content;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberBtnClick.Content;
    }
}

//OnPropertyChanged
public string OutputValue
{
    get
    {
        return _outputValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _outputValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("OutputValue");
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Mark

So, after following some of the suggestions of RareNCool, this is what I've come up. There are still a few issues to work out like focus on the textbox, but otherwise it's working.

In my View I just added another Bind to the ViewModel KeyRoutedEventArgs event:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="OutputValueTextBlock"
                   IsTextSelectionEnabled="True"
                   KeyDown="{x:Bind ViewModel.OnKeyboardNumberInput, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.OutputValue, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
```

And in the ViewModel I created this event:

```
  public void OnKeyboardNumberInput(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key == VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || (isOperationPerformed))
            _outputValue = "";

        if ((e.Key > VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key < VirtualKey.Number9) || (e.Key > VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key < VirtualKey.NumberPad9))
        {
            string numberKey = e.Key.ToString();

            if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Decimal)
            {
                isOperationPerformed = false;

                if (!_outputValue.Contains("."))
                {
                    // Switch if E.Key is a decimal and _output does not contains a decimal.
                    switch (numberKey)
                    {
                        case "Decimal":
                            numberKey = ".";
                            OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Swtich if E.Key is not a decimal.
                switch (numberKey)
                {
                    case "Number0":
                    case "NumberPad0":
                        numberKey = "0";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number1":
                    case "NumberPad1":
                        numberKey = "1";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number2":
                    case "NumberPad2":
                        numberKey = "2";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number3":
                    case "NumberPad3":
                        numberKey = "3";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number4":
                    case "NumberPad4":
                        numberKey = "4";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number5":
                    case "NumberPad5":
                        numberKey = "5";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number6":
                    case "NumberPad6":
                        numberKey = "6";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number7":
                    case "NumberPad7":
                        numberKey = "7";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number8":
                    case "NumberPad8":
                        numberKey = "8";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                    case "Number9":
                    case "NumberPad9":
                        numberKey = "9";
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + numberKey;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put the actual handling into a separate function with a `string` parameter, then catch the Button `Click` and Page `KeyDown` events and pass in their content. However, if you really want to have just one function, you can bind both the `Click` and `KeyDown` events to the function with both parameters typed as `objects`, then use `typeof` to determine what you'll need to get from them.

Comment: I'm really struggling with keyboard input. Some sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: I've taken your advice and am implementing a separate function, but am struggling with three issues. 1 How to wire it up with the ViewModel. 2. How to convert a VirtualKey enum to a string. 3 How to set focus in the View.

Comment: I've created an event in the ViewModel like so: public void OnKeyboardNumberInput(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key > VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key<VirtualKey.Number9)
            {
                if (e.Key > VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key<VirtualKey.NumberPad9)
                {

Comment: But how to pull the key char out?                     VirtualKey virtualKey = (VirtualKey)sender;

                    if (virtualKey ???)
                    {
                        if (!_outputValue.Contains("."))
                        {
                            OutputValue = OutputValue + virtualKey.???;
                        }
}
                    else
                    {
                        OutputValue = OutputValue + virtualKey.???;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Basically create an event like this: void Do_Something(string number) { //Do your stuff } and that's what you'd hand in the button's content or the key to. You could do a bunch of `if`s or `? :`s to get the key, but if you're wanting to do key mapping that's a whole different question that's already been asked.

Comment: I don't need key mapping, I just need to pass the key's value through to the ViewModel's OnKeyboardNumberInput event. With a button that it easy, I've got it bound to the button's Click x:Bind. But with a Key I'm not sure. Somehow I have to acquire focus in the View, and then bind it to the ViewModel's OnKeyboardNumberInput  event. After reading about x:Bind, it doesn't look like you can do an x:Bind in code to a View Model, so I'm stuck there. Maybe I can use an x:Binding method in the View's code behind?

Comment: Without testing, I'd say the quickest way to get the value (if it's always a number) would be to just grab the last character off the end of the value (since, if I remember correctly, it comes out as "Number6").

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it comes out as NumPad6 or Number6. I can use a switch statement to output the desired string. Next, how can I call the OnKeyboardNumberInput KeyRoutedEventArgs event from my View's Code Behind file? I need a method to grab focus and then route the VirtualKey to the Event. I see that there are so low level System32 methods that I could use, but I'm not sure that I need that low a level.

Comment: Thank you RareNCool! I edited my question above with the code which solved most of the issue.

Comment: Glad it worked. Looks like you got the event binding working :) Though I actually don't think you'd need all the switches; something like: `numberString.Substring(numberString.Length - 2, 1)` would get you the number, I think.